# Do you need to use a default in switch statement JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is a straight up question, but in a `switch` statement is it ok not to return a `default` state?

The switch statement is in a React Component and looks like this.

```
const App = (chosenTeam) => {
    const renderSection = (team) => {
        switch (team) {
          case 'LFC':
            return <Liverpool />;
          case 'MUFC':
            return <TerribleTeam />;
          case 'Chelsea':
            return <Blues />;
        }
    }

    return {renderSection(chosenTeam)}
}
```

Comment: it is fine. without, you get `undefined` as result of the function, if that is the alue, you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's optional refer to [`switch on MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> `default` **Optional**
>
> A default clause; if provided, this clause is executed if the value of expression doesn't match any of the case clauses.

Regardless, you should use a dictionary object instead of switch:

```
const team = {
  LFC: <Liverpool />,
  MUFC: <TerribleTeam />,
  Chelsea: <Blues />
};

const App = chosenTeam => <>{team[chosenTeam]}</>;
```

The main aspect is that you are getting all functionalities of [an object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

---

Note, rendering components inside the component body may cause performance tradeoffs (unless they memoize):

```
const App = chosenTeam => {
  //         v Executed on *every* render
  const renderSection = team => { ... };

  return <>...</>;
};
```

```
//        v Should be in the outer scope if you keeping the function
const renderSection = team => {
  switch (team) { ... }
};

const App = chosenTeam => {
  return <>...</>;
};
```

Comment: thanks @Dennis! Why would you say dictionary over switch? Just because it is tidier?

Comment: @peterflanagan I'll try adding an explanation about the object

Comment: The main key is that you are getting all functionalities of the object, like `Object.entries` so you can map it and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* that the switched value will be in one of the stated cases, then no, the default case is unnecessary, because it'll never be reached.

But `switch` can be error-prone and unnecessarily verbose in many cases. You might consider using an object indexed by team name instead:

```
const teams = {
  LFC: () => (<Liverpool />),
  MUFC: () => (<TerribleTeam />),
  Chelsea: () => (<Blues />)
}
const App = (chosenTeam) => {
  return {teams[chosenTeam]()}
}
```